# Linq Query - Find two most recent TimeStamps for each distinct Column A

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a DB table called Visits with three columns; ContactId, DateOfContact and LocationId.

Each row of the table represents a contact signing in at a certain LocationId, and the DateOfContact timestamp represents the time that they signed in.

I'm wanting to query the table to find the two most recent visit instances of each ContactId in the last 24 hours, i.e. the most recent two records of them signing in.

If they only have one visit record from the last 24 hours the list should still contain that single record.

So I currently just select the SINGLE most recent visit record of each contact in the last 24 hours like this:

```
var result = _context.Visits
            .Where(d => LocIds.Contains(d.LocationId) && DateOfContact >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
            .GroupBy(d => d.ContactId)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Max(d => d.DateOfContact))
            .Select(d => new { d.FirstOrDefault().ContactId, d.FirstOrDefault().DateOfContact }).ToList();
```

and I'd like the last TWO visits instead.

Something like this

ContactId. . . . . DateOfContact

1 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 13:11:00

1 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 12:11:00

2 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 11:11:00

2 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 10:11:00

3 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 09:11:00

4 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 08:11:00

4 . . . . . . . . . . . 08/06/2015 07:11:00

In a list.

Can I achieve this? I tried implementing a Take(2) but couldn't really make it work.

Thanks,
JK

Comment: .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateOfContact) and .Take(2) doenst work?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way using that, but I couldn't figure where to place the .Take(2). Placing it before or after the select just cuts the list to the two most recent records before creating my new list. I can't figure how to implement it instead of the FirstOrDefault in the Select function where I think it really needs to be.

Comment: You have to place it in the Select ;)  Serv gave you the answer.

Comment: Sorted, thankyou. Knew I was being stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Take()` should do the trick:

```
var result = source.Where(x => x.DateOfContact >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                   .GroupBy (x => x.ContactId)
                   .OrderBy(g => g.Max(d => d.DateOfContact))
                   .Select(x => x.Take(2));
```

If you want to flatten the list, just append a `.SelectMany(x => x);`

Demo code: http://share.linqpad.net/9gxjcc.linq

Comment: This successfully separates them out and is a big step towards what I want but I've ended up with kind of a 2d array where result is a list of 1/2 visit lists. Kinda like result = {visit}, {visit, visit}, {visit, visit} etc..........How could I make it just one long list that reads like my makeshift list/table at the bottom of my question?

Comment: use `SelectMany(x => x)` this flattens the list and gets rid of the grouping